# How do member Initializers work in Structs ? (In Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cs193p, member-initialization

Since I am a complete beginner, I don't even know whether I am asking the right question or not. But I am having trouble understand why the "***User(name: "John ...)***" part of the code *in the for loop* works

```
    CASE1
 struct User
 {
    let name: String
    let company: String
    let login: String
    let password: String



 static let database: Dictionary<String, User> = {
    var theDatabase = Dictionary<String, User>()
    for user in [
        User(name: "John Appleseed", company: "Apple", login: "japple", password: "foo"),
        User(name: "Madison Bumgarner", company: "World Champion San Francisco Giants", login: "madbum", password: "foo"),
        User(name: "John Hennessy", company: "Stanford", login: "hennessy", password: "foo"),
        User(name: "Bad Guy", company: "Criminals, Inc.", login: "baddie", password: "foo")
    ] {
        theDatabase[user.login] = user
    }
    return theDatabase
}()
```

}

but this doesn't

```
 CASE2 
struct User
   {
let name: String
let company: String
let login: String
let password: String

  for user in User(name: "John Appleseed", company: "Apple", login: "japple", password: "foo"){
print(user)

}
```

}

To understand how CASE1 works I ran a simpler version of this code i.e. CASE2. Even though the exact same thing is happening in both cases,[ Regarding User(..arguments..) ] I get the  error  "Declaration Expected" in the second case.
Sir Paul(Stanford cs193p) said this was a fairly simple database , but I have been trying to figure this problem out for more than 6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for-loops must be contained in closures.

In case 1, you are declaring a static property called `database` using a closure. This is the declaration:

```
static let database: Dictionary<String, User> = {
    // This is the body of the closure
}()
```

And you put the for-loop in the closure body. This tells the swift compiler when to execute the for-loop, which is when the closure is executed.

In case 2, the for-loop is in the struct. But a struct isn't a closure. So the swift compiler does not know when to execute the for-loop.

The only things that can be in a struct are declarations, such as property declarations, function declarations and struct declarations. A for-loop isn't a declaration so that's why the compiler complains that it expected to see a declaration.

The code in case 1 works because the `database` is a property declaration.

---

But... there's another problem!

For-in loops only loops through objects that conform to the `SequenceType` protocol. Examples of such objects include arrays and `String.CharatcerView`.

In case 1, the for-in loop loops through an array, which conforms to `SequenceType`. See those `[` and `]`? They denote an array! In case 2, you don't have those around the newly created `User`, so it is just a `User`, which does not conform to `SequenceType` and thus cannot be used in a for-in loop.

To solve both of your problems, use this code:

```
struct User
{
    let name: String
    let company: String
    let login: String
    let password: String



    static let database: Dictionary<String, User> = {
        var theDatabase = Dictionary<String, User>()
        for user in [
            User(name: "John Appleseed", company: "Apple", login: "japple", password: "foo")] {
                theDatabase[user.login] = user
        }
        return theDatabase
    }()
}
```

As you can see, I added a declaration of `database` and the closure and added `[]` around the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. 
The **for in [*collection*]** give you ability to iterate on array, dictionary or another collection. In case 1 you create array of Users:

```
[
User(), User()
]
```

but in case 2 you don't. 
This syntax: **[** User(),User(),User() **]** create an array.